# Replaying Kafka events stored in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka

I might be thinking of this incorrectly, but we're looking to set up a connection between Kafka and S3. We are using Kafka as the backbone of our microservice event sourcing system and may occasionally need to replay events from the beginning of time in certain scenarios (i.e. building a new service, rebuilding a corrupted database view).

Instead of storing events indefinitely in AWS EBS storage ($0.10/GB/mo.), we'd like to shift them to S3 ($0.023/Gb/mo. or less) after seven days using the [S3 Sink Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/overview.html) and eventually continually move them down the chain of S3 storage levels.

However, I don't understand that if I need to replay a topic from the beginning to restore a service, how would Kafka get that data back on demand from S3? I know I can utilize a source connector, but it seems that is only for setting up a new topic. Not for pulling data back from an existing topic.

Answer (score 2):

The Confluent S3 Source Connector doesn't dictate where the data is written back into. But you may want to refer the [storage configuration properties](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-source/current/configuration_options.html#storage-parameters) regarding `topics.dir` and `topic` relationship.

Alternatively, write some code to read your S3 events and send them into a Kafka producer client.

Keep in mind, for your recovery payment calculations that reads from different tiers of S3 cost more and more.

You may also want to follow the developments of Kafka native tiered storage support (or similarly, look at Apache Pulsar as an alternative)

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the dynamic of reading from S3 would work? For example, we have a Kafka cluster that retains data for seven days but writes all events to S3 for backup. I am confused about how the connection between S3 and Kafka would be triggered. If I have a consumer with the `--from-beginning` flag, how would the topic know to pull data from S3 as well?

Comment: As mentioned, there are two options. 1) [S3 Source Connector (Backup and Restore)](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-source/current/index.html) 2) You use native S3 SDK methods to read files out of the buckets, then parse them into `ProducerRecord` objects and send them. Or, with tiered storage, the consumer would natively/transparently know how to read from S3 via the broker APIs

Comment: Some documentation on tiered storage (within Confluent Platform only for now) - https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/architecture/tiered-storage/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Suppose I have a source connector and a sink connector tied to the same S3 bucket and ran 50 GB of data through a Kafka topic with the topic retaining data only for 24 hours. Wouldn't the source connector re-push the same 50 GB to the topic daily, causing even more problems?

Comment: I've not used the S3 source connector, but it should track its position (as most source connectors do) within the bucket and not constantly republish the same events. Only when you start removing files before it has read them will you start to see issues

Comment: Ahhh. There is the secret sauce. I didn't know that it tracked its offset in the source connector. Can you add that to your original answer?